# Running 32 bit and 64 bit web projects side by side from VS 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have got a setup where we need to integrate a third party dll into our ASP.Net MVC web project. Our application is a 64 bit one. But the third party just offers a 32-bit dll. To make things simpler for us, we have written a wrapper (basically a web api project) around this third party dll. We have added this as a service reference in our main app. We are using VS 2015, and have explicitly checked the box in *Tools->Options->Projects->Web Projects->Use 64 bit IIS*. This was done because we were facing frequent out of memory exceptions from the application. But, due to this, we are not able to either consume or debug the project containing 32 bit dll. To overcome this, we have hosted the wrapper project as 32 bit web api in our QA environment, and we directly consume it. Now, I have been asked to look into a few issues in it. Is there a way that I can debug by using 64 bit iis express for our main app and 32 bit iis express for the wrapper, from two different instances of VS 2015 on a single box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try hosting the application in iis - 32 bit version and find the pid and attach process i think it should work to do for both